# Can big-step semantics express evaluation order?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

Can you express evaluation order using big-step semantics?

For example, in a simple language consisting of only `if t then t else t` and `true` and `false`, we can decide to only step a `if then else` to one of its branches if its branches are already values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can big-step semantics express the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We prefer that you avoid using images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). It's better to transcribe text and mathematics.  Note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I realize that.  But the question is on Computer Science now, and we have our own standards here that may be slightly different from Stack Overflow (partly reflecting common patterns we see here, such as the one I mentioned in my comment).  You can edit the question to reflect CS.SE's norms by clicking the "edit" button underneath the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot express evaluation order using big-step semantics.

Borrowing from Benjamin Pierce: big-step semantics is a multi-step evaluation relation that directly formulates the notion of "this term evaluates to that final value". So it cannot impose the kind of evaluation order you describe.

Also keep in mind what the horizontal bar represents. Again borrowing from Pierce: If we have established the statements in the premise(s) listed above the line, then we may derive the conclusion below the line. It would not make sense to impose an ordering on the premises to draw the conclusion.